# ExpressJS app.locals.title gives: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, javascript-globalize

I am new to ExpressJS, so I wanted to set a simple string value, I could translate.

So I tried out [globalize-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/globalize-express) and set the app title like this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("App: " + req.Globalize.formatMessage('strings/title'));
    res.locals.title = req.Globalize.formatMessage('strings/title');
    next();
});
```

followed by:

```
app.use('/', index);
```

It looks like it is rendering correctly, but the console is posting the error:

> Can't set headers after they are sent.

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Comment: Correct, found that in my `index.js`, I should call `router.get('/', function (req, res)`. I.e. No need to call `next()` in the `router.get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the error was in the related `routes/index.js`, there was scaffolded another `next()` call. I updated that file to:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = require("../app.js");
    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index', {
        });
    });

    module.exports = router;
```